Work-energy theorem confusion
I know that:
$$W = \Delta KE$$
and that:
$$ME = KE + PE$$
I got confused about one problem my teacher did why did he use:
$$W = \Delta ME $$
The problem in question is shown below:

Your cat, the Milanese (mass 7.00 kg), is trying to reach the top of a frictionless ramp 2.00 m long, which has
an inclination of 30 degrees above the horizontal.
Since the poor feline has no traction on the ramp, you push him at all times by exerting a constant force of 100 N
parallel to the ramp. If Milaneso starts running
from further back, so that it has a speed
of 2.40 m/s at the base of the ramp, what speed will it have when it reaches the highest part? Use the
work-energy theorem.

I was trying to understand why my teacher used this equation. I think he did this because we subtract the force of gravity acting on the cat with that of the force done by the human:
$$W = F(D)-mgh = KE_2-KE_1$$
however, the teacher has
$$W = KE_2+mgh - KE_1$$
Is work always change of mechanical energy or just in this particular exercise ?

Please do not delete and repost closed questions. Original question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/816270/174766

@VincentThacker I edited and improved the question, sir but it was not reopened

When saving the edit, you need to tick the box to submit for review. Then it will be considered for reopening. You have not done that.

This is a question which shows the importance of defining the system at the start. The first equation after the problem is the cat alone as the system and the second equation is the cat and Earth as the system. If the question is opened I can explain more fully.

I don't like all these formulae and talk of the 'work-energy theorem'. I'd simply say....   Human work input = Cat's gain in Gravitational PE + Cat's gain in KE.

The net force on the cat is the sum of two individual forces: (1) the force due to you pushing on the cat; (2) the gravitational force due to the earth on the cat. The work done by the force of gravity on the cat is the negative change in gravitational potential energy. The net work is the change in kinetic energy of the cat. Therefore the work done by you pushing on the cat is the change in total mechanical energy of the cat...


I know that:
$$W = \Delta KE$$

This equation is only applicable when $W$ denotes the work due to the net force.

and that:
$$ME = KE + PE$$

Ok.

I got confused about one problem my teacher did why did he use:
$$W = \Delta ME $$

This equation is only applicable when $W$ does not denote the work due to the net force (unless the potential energy is constant). Here, the symbol $W$ presumably means the force due to you pushing the cat (see below) and excludes the force due to gravity.

The problem in question is shown below:

Your cat, the Milanese (mass 7.00 kg), is trying to reach the top of a frictionless ramp 2.00 m long, which has
an inclination of 30 degrees above the horizontal.
Since the poor feline has no traction on the ramp, you push him at all times by exerting a constant force of 100 N
parallel to the ramp. If Milaneso starts running
from further back, so that it has a speed
of 2.40 m/s at the base of the ramp, what speed will it have when it reaches the highest part? Use the
work-energy theorem.


Presumably your professor's symbol $W$ is doing double duty by denoting both the net work (as in your first equation) as well as the work done by just your force on the cat (as in your second equation).
In the problem you presented, there are two different forces acting on the cat: (1) $\vec F_{you}$ due to you pushing (or pulling) on the cat; and (2) $\vec F_{grav}$ due to the earth pushing (or pulling) on the cat.
The net force is:
$$
\vec F_{net} = \vec F_{you} + \vec F_{grav}
$$
The net work is:
$$
W_{net} = \int \vec F_{net}\cdot d\vec x = \int \vec F_{you}\cdot d\vec x + \int \vec F_{grav}\cdot d\vec x \tag{A}
$$
Your teacher is using the symbol $W$ in your second equation to mean only the work done by $\vec F_{you}$, not the net work, therefore we can rewrite Eq. (A) as:
$$
W = W_{net} - \int \vec F_{grav}\cdot d\vec x
$$
$$
=\Delta KE - \int \vec F_{grav}\cdot d\vec x
$$
$$
=\Delta KE + \int \frac{\partial PE}{\partial \vec x}\cdot d\vec x
$$
$$
=\Delta KE + \Delta PE = \Delta ME\;,
$$
where the second equality above is from the work-kinetic-energy theorem and the third equality above is from the definition of the gravitational force as a conservatives force (which is the negative gradient of the associated potential energy function).
